# Instant Image Uploading and Scaling

Tags: fine-uploader

Im trying to achieve something like this. These were recorded from some sites I came across. Im talking about how it uploads images almost instant, not about template.
I used a 3.5 mb image.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnGsJuyWs9s

So far I've managed to achieve this by copy/pasting codes:
http://adspottest.cf/simple-thumbnails.html

I don't have lot of knowledge in these things. I managed to do this with the knowledge I picked up here and there.

My questions are:

1. When scaling is on, if I upload several big images at once (like 2mb, 3mb), some images don't generate the preview correctly.
2. When scaling is off, above error doesn't occur. But it doesn't upload image almost instantly. Is it possible to turn scaling off AND upload the images instantly?
3. Im trying to get this work for a classified site. In this site the placeholder for image is a fixed one (640 x 480).

As you can see I have set scaling.sizes: maxSize option to 640

If I upload a 5500 x 3010 image; it will be scaled to 640 x 350. This is OK as it doesn't go over the website placeholder max width.
But if I upload a 3010 x 5500 image; it will be scaled to 350 x 640. That means it goes over the placeholder max height. I need it to be scaled to 263 x 480.

So is it possible to set max width AND height?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you mean by "upload images instantly". Files are always uploaded as quickly as your network connection allows. Also, there are no known issues with the latest version of Fine Uploader regarding image preview generation. This is a stable feature that hasn't changed much in some time. If you are able to reproduce what you believe to be a bug, submit a bug report with all of your code and detailed reproduction steps in the project's issue tracker at https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/new.

Regarding your final question, all images will be scaled proportionately, taking aspect ratio into account. As a result, you are asked to provide the largest length or width. Which you provide is not significant - you should simply provide the largest size of any side and Finr Uploader will scale it appropriately. There is no feature that allows you to specify both a max width and height. Please file a feature request if you'd like to see this in a future version.

Comment: When I said "upload images instantly" I meant this.
Go to:
http://www.quikr.com/post-classifieds-ads/?postadcategoryid=18222212777

It takes me nearly 1 min to upload a 3.5mb image to above site.

But in the sites I show in the video, it doesn't take more than 3 seconds to upload a same size image.

As you can see in the test site I managed to setup, when scaling is enabled, even a 5 mb image uploads in less than 5 seconds.

That's what I meant by instant uploads.
Problem is it doesn't work right if I select few large images when scaling is on.

Thanks

Comment: I assume Open-Classifieds is using your script.
Check a test Open Classified installation I setup here:
http://adspottest.cf/openclass/publish-new.html

If you upload a big image there, it will upload in seconds.
I see the same thing in Fine Uploader "Gallery View for Images" demo.

I want mine to work like that.

Thanks

Comment: Again, the upload speed has nothing to do with the upload library you are using, and everything to do with your internet connection.

Comment: OK. Lets forget about everything I've said so far.
Kindly go here:
http://adspottest.cf/simple-thumbnails.html

Select two or more images bigger than 2mb and start upload. You'll notice, it doesn't show thumb for some images.
Im NOT saying its a bug. Im just saying its possible that I did something wrong. 
So I need your help to figure out what it could be?

Thanks

Comment: previews look fine to me - but your server occasionally returns bad responses - you'll want to look into that

Comment: Turns out it was a browser problem.
I just tried in Chrome 47 and its working.
Firefox Dev Edition 42 is OK too.
Problem was in Firefox 38.

Thanks